# commits don't trigger a build in circleci

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

In below link, I can see that it's sending commits to circleci but in circleCI, commits don't show up.

https://github.com/org/repo/settings/hooks/

the circled one is the one having the problem, Is there any reason why It's showing another icon compared to other projects??

[image]

**circleci**

```
env: &env
  docker:
    - image: circleci/node:10.3.0
  working_directory: ~/repo

version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    <<: *env
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: npm install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      - run: npm run test
      - run: npm run build

  deploy:
    <<: *env
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          - v1-dependencies-

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          required:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the "Needs Setup" icon. It's impossible to tell from here what's causing that icon to come up though. If your project isn't public, so that you may share it on here, then I'd suggest opening a Support ticket.